# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc returns null

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So im trying to make a basic login page but I get this error:

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Note: Im a beginner to PHP so please try not to overcomplicate things a little bit

This is my PHP Code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$username}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if (password_verify($password, $row["password"])){
                session_start();
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row["id"];

                header("Location: home.php");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo'<div style="background-color:crimson;">Incorrect Password</div>';
            }
        } else {
            echo'<div style="background-color:crimson;">User not Found</div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal`.

Comment: You have run the `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` twice, so you already consumed the resultset when you did it in the IF, therefore the second one has no results and returns none

Comment: Soo do I just do 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row > 0){
  ...

Comment: The usual approach is to use a while as in the examples in [The PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: You should not be using `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`. At least not in the way you are using it now.

Comment: It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-